# There is already an open Data Reader associated with this Command which must be closed first.?8

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to save image file into db in binary format. And retrieve those binary files and display the image on my web page. While using the given below code one error has been generated. Please help me.

```
public partial class Default3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    static SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"connectionString");
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            filldropdown();
        }
    }

    private void filldropdown()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select EmpID from Tbl_Emp", con);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        TextBox3.Items.Clear();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                TextBox3.Items.Add(dr["EmpID"].ToString());
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Tbl_Emp values(@id,@name,@image)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox2.Text);

        int img = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;

        byte[] msdata = new byte[img];

        FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(msdata, 0, img);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", msdata);

        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
        filldropdown();
        Response.Write("Data Saved ....");

    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Tbl_Emp where EmpID=@id", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", TextBox3.Text);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows && dr.Read())
        {
            TextBox1.Text = dr["EmpID"].ToString();
            TextBox2.Text = dr["EmpName"].ToString();
            Image1.ImageUrl = "Handler.ashx?EmpID=" + TextBox3.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Record With This ID Note Found");
        }
    }
}
```

Source:

```
<div>
      Enter ID  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
      Enter Name <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
      Enter Pic  <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /><br />
      <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="Button1_Click" /><br >
      <asp:Image ID="Image1"  runat="server" Height="137px" Width="130px" /><br /> 
      <asp:DropDownList ID="TextBox3" runat="server">
      </asp:DropDownList>
      <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Search" onclick="Button2_Click" />
```

Data Table:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct answer.

```
public partial class Default3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    static SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"connectionString");
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            filldropdown();
        }
    }

    private void filldropdown()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select EmpID from Tbl_Emp", con);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        TextBox3.Items.Clear();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                TextBox3.Items.Add(dr["EmpID"].ToString());
            }
        }
        dr.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Tbl_Emp values(@id,@name,@image)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox2.Text);

        int img = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;

        byte[] msdata = new byte[img];

        FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(msdata, 0, img);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", msdata);

        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
        filldropdown();
        Response.Write("Data Saved ....");

    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Tbl_Emp where EmpID=@id", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", TextBox3.Text);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows && dr.Read())
        {
            TextBox1.Text = dr["EmpID"].ToString();
            TextBox2.Text = dr["EmpName"].ToString();
            Image1.ImageUrl = "Handler.ashx?EmpID=" + TextBox3.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Record With This ID Note Found");
        }
        dr.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to handle cleaning up SQL Connections, Commands and Readers is with the `using` statement.  Also you don't really need to keep the connection as a static field based on the code you've posted.  Here's basically what I would do in each method

```
protected void Some_Action(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"connectionString"))
    {
        con.Open();
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Query Here", con))
        {
            // Do stuff with the command here like setting Parameters.
            using(SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // Do stuff with the reader here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will ensure that your Connection, Command, and Reader are disposed even if an exception occurs.

Answer (score 2):

You have to close SqlDataReader object before opening new one because it is runtime object..

like this close id

```
 dr.Close();
```

Comment: Why post basically the same answer twice instead of editing this one?

Answer (score 0):

It Will be Better to Use `Using` which will Automatically `Dispose` Your Connection/Readers what Your Have Open

Like

```
    using(SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection)
    {
     SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(con,"query")
     ....
    using(SqlDataReader dr=cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
      {        ....
      }
    }
```

But You can use like this In your Existing Code

```
private void filldropdown()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select EmpID from Tbl_Emp", con);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        TextBox3.Items.Clear();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                TextBox3.Items.Add(dr["EmpID"].ToString());
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    dr.Close
    }





protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Tbl_Emp where EmpID=@id", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", TextBox3.Text);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows && dr.Read())
        {
            TextBox1.Text = dr["EmpID"].ToString();
            TextBox2.Text = dr["EmpName"].ToString();
            Image1.ImageUrl = "Handler.ashx?EmpID=" + TextBox3.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Record With This ID Note Found");
        }
    dr.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Is there really a point in posting an answer that just combines two already existing answers?

Comment: @juharr Actually its due to Inter Net Connection.During Answering I Already SAW Only 1 Incomplete Answer